# Git pull problems with gitignore

Tags: git, sqlite, gitignore, git-pull

I've added my files to the gitignore:

```
db/development.sqlite3
log/development.log
```

And I've removed them from tracking on both my local computer and server:

```
git rm --cached db/development.sqlite3
git rm --cached log/development.log
```

Then I push from my local computer to the repo, and pull to the server using

```
git pull origin master
```

and I still get this error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be removed by merge:
        db/development.sqlite3
        log/development.log
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
```

I do not want these files overwritten or deleted, I just want git to pull everything and ignore the existing files that store my database information.  How do I get past this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
$ mv db/development.sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3_bak
$ mv log/development.log log/development.log_bak

$ git pull
$ rm db/development.sqlite3 log/development.log

$ mv db/development.sqlite3_bak db/development.sqlite3
$ mv log/development.log_bak log/development.log
```

Comment: This looks like it would work, but the db/ file is all of my database data.  If I want to frequently update my site, I would have to move the file back and forth everytime I pull an update, whereas I'd rather just be able to pull without worrying.

Comment: No you won't, since you've added them to `.gitignore` from now on git will just ignore them.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, you are basically copying the files to new _bak files, then after the pull, copying them back to the original file name?  I guess I'm just confused as to why the .gitignore isn't just ignoring them from the start?

Comment: Because they are already present in the remote repo, therefore the `git pull` brings them to your local repo.

Comment: This seems to have worked, the only thing I had to do different was do the `rm` command before the `pull`, and it was `git rm` rather than just `rm`.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 "solutions" here.
You can either copy the files somewhere else, do a pull, remove them completely, push and then copy back the other files.

Or you could do

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

This will cause the files to be removed on the server but they will be kept locally. Afterwards you won't need to do this again because of your .gitignore. That file will only be applied to files that weren't already tracked.

Comment: Two things - will that stash untracked files away? And what about later pulls, won't they conflict too? I thought of stashing them too, but I'm not very sure about that two details.

Comment: I'm not sure about the stash. But temporarily copying them somewhere else, pulling, remove the files, pushing it back and then copying back the files will.